# How do I correct the year in the date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a `date` field for `users.birth_date`.
This field contains a date, for example, `Mon, 18 Dec 1989`.
How to take this date into account in the current year, for example, `Mon, 18 Dec 2021`
I do this so that I know the exact day of the week (1-Monday, 2-Tuesday,...) in the current year.
To find the day of the week in the date from the `users.birth_date` field, I do this:

```
extract(dow from users.birth_date::timestamp) IN (1,2,3)
```

how can I convert the date to find out what day of the week the user's birthday is in the current year?

Comment: Is `birth_date` defined with the `date` data type?

Comment: yes, `birth_date` is `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to get the birth date in the current year based on the birth date with the year saved in your database.

This should do the trick for you:

```
select extract(dow from format('%s-%s-%s', extract(year from now()), extract(month from users.birth_date), extract(day from users.birth_date))::date) from users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `to_char` and `to_date` might do the trick. See the following examples:

```
WITH users (birth_date) AS (
  VALUES (to_date('Mon, 18 Dec 1989','Dy, DD Mon YYYY'))
)
SELECT 
 birth_date,
 to_char(birth_date,'Dy, DD Mon YYYY'),
 extract(dow from birth_date) dow_1,
 to_date(extract(year from current_date)||
         to_char(birth_date,'-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'),
 to_char((extract(year from current_date)||
         to_char(birth_date,'-mm-dd'))::date,'Dy, DD Mon YYYY'),
 extract(dow from to_date(extract(year from current_date)||
         to_char(birth_date,'-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')) dow_2
FROM users;

 birth_date |     to_char      | dow_1 |  to_date   |     to_char      | dow_2 
------------+------------------+-------+------------+------------------+-------
 1989-12-18 | Mon, 18 Dec 1989 |     1 | 2021-12-18 | Sat, 18 Dec 2021 |     6
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the year fields into current year.
You can calculate the year difference, then add it back to the original date.

```
SELECT ( 
    TO_DATE('1989-02-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (
      INTERVAL '1 year' * (
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) -
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('1989-02-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
      )
   )  
)
```

It is still a date, so you can do anything that you can apply on date.
Such as `EXTRACT(dow, [date])`;

Use  `+ INTERVAL  X * '1 YEAR'` can prevent you generateing invalid date in leap years.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . You can remove your comment.  The OP fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `make_date()` for this:

```
select birth_date, 
       make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, 
                 extract(month from birth_date)::int, 
                 extract(day from birth_date)::int) as this_years_date
from users;
```

A view that does this for you would probably be helpful if you need this a lot. Then you can use `extract(dow from this_years_date)` while selecting from the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  EXTRACT(DOW FROM cast(to_date(to_char(now(),'yyyy')||to_char(users.birth_date,'-MM-dd')||' 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as TIMESTAMP));
```

1.string contact current year and users.birth_date
2.string convert to date